# Call super make must be first statement in method

Tags: java

If inherited method does not contain a call to super in first statement, I need a compile error, requires constructor-like behavior. Is it possible to do this?

```
public class ModelBase {
    protected int defaultCount;

    public void init() {
        defaultCount = 10;
    }
}

public class Model extends ModelBase {
    @Override
    public void init() {
        System.out.println(defaultCount);
        super.init();//need error or notification
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that requiring a call to super at all [is considered an anti-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_super), in part because there is no way to enforce it, or to enforce that it is called at the right point in the method etc.

One way to do this with plain Java is not to require a call to super at all, but rather to provide a non-overrideable method which calls a subclass-specific method at the right time.

For example:

```
class YourClass {
  final void yourMethod() {
    // Stuff you want to happen first.

    // and then at the end, call 
    subclassSpecific();
  }

  protected void subclassSpecific() {}
}
```

Now, subclasses can override that method to provide specific behavior that will occur after the rest of the things in `yourMethod`:

```
class YourSubclass extends YourClass {
  @Override protected void subclassSpecific() {
    // Whatever.
  }
}
```